# Http Exception in try and catch blocks

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have a translation service which translates the strings thrown as an HTTP Exception. It works fine when it is not thrown inside a `try{...} catch{...} block`. But works outside of it.

```js
  async getEmployeeByEmail(emailRaw: string): Promise<Employee> {
    try {
      const employee = await this.employeeRepository.findOne({
        relations: ['buildingAssignedAsLead'],
        where: {
          email: emailRaw,
        },
      });
      if (!employee) {
        return null;
      }

      return employee;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new HttpException(
        'translations.EMAILS.INVALID_EMAIL',
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }
```

I have an exception Response Filter which translates the message based on `'translations.EMAILS.INVALID_EMAIL'` but while accessing the response from exception it is not getting the same string.

And hence it cannot be translated.
When throwing httpException inside a catch block i get exception to be an object like :

```
{status: ..., message: Invalid Email, ...}
```

and when not throwing inside a catch block it comes like
`translations.EMAILS.INVALID_EMAIL`

What can be done to make catch block send the same response?

Answer (score -1):

you are passing email that is not present in your database.
pass valid email that present in your database.

Comment: You didnt understand the question properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).